# Delete file in sharepoint from a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload and later delete a file from a sharepoint site. Uploads works fine but I get an error for the deleting.

Here is my code:

```
  private void UploadSharePoint(string siteNumber, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ClientContext client = new ClientContext("https://sites.company.com/sites/" + siteNumber + "/"))
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pw", "domain");
                var formLib = client.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                client.Load(formLib.RootFolder);
                client.ExecuteQuery();

                //File Upload
                var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation
                {
                    Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName),
                    Overwrite = true,
                    Url = Path.Combine("Documents/99_Upload", Path.GetFileName(fileName))
                };
                var uploadFile = formLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
                client.Load(uploadFile);
                client.ExecuteQuery();

                //File Delete
                Web web = client.Web;
                List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("mydoc");
                client.Load(list);  --> here I get nothing back
                Folder folder = list.RootFolder;
                client.Load(folder);
                FileCollection files = folder.Files;
                client.Load(files);
                client.ExecuteQuery(); 
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = files[1];
                file.DeleteObject();
                client.ExecuteQuery(); 
           }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Error message:

> {"List 'mydoc' does not exist at site with URL 'https://sites.company.com/sites/333333'."}

So something must be wrong with my input for deleting `List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("mydoc");`

The title as shown in Sharepoint is mydoc. The filename is mydoc.txt. I tried both but nothing works.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error message thrown is correct:

> {"List 'mydoc' does not exist at site with URL 'https://sites.company.com/sites/333333'."}

The issue is you are creating a **SharePoint List item** with title "mydoc", but then you are trying to access a **SharePoint List** with title "mydoc" which is not present. See the updated code below:

```
            //File Delete
            Web web = client.Web;
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            client.Load(list);  --> here you will get reference to the list

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Documents/mydoc.txt");
            client.Load(file);
            file.DeleteObject();
            client.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Glad I could help!